# Validators for reactive form not passing from parent form component to child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a parent form component that is using a child form component. I am using Angular reactive forms. I have no issues setting the values in the child form component, but the validators are no longer working. In the parent form, I have instantiated the form group similar to the following:

```
this.editUserForm = this.fb.group ({
  phone: ['123-456-1234'],
  fax: [null],
  email: [null],
  website: [null],
  editUserForm_Address : this.fb.group ({
    address1: ['123 Elm Street', Validators.required],
    address2: [null],
    city: ['Dummy City', Validators.required],
    state: ['Dummy State', Validators.required],
    zipcode: ['11111', Validators.required],
    country: ['USA', Validators.required]
  })
});
```

The parent component html uses the child component:

```
<form [formGroup] = "editUserForm">
<address-form formGroupName = "editUserForm_Address"></address-form>
</form>
```

The child component class is like:

```
export class AddressFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public addressFormGroup: FormGroup;

  @Input()

  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addressFormGroup = <FormGroup>this.controlContainer.control;
  }

}
```

The child component html is like this (just Address 1 for an example):

```
   <ng-container [formGroup] = "addressFormGroup">   
    <div class = "row">
     <div class = "form-group col-12" [ngClass]="{'error': (addressFormGroup.controls['address1'].errors)">
       <label for="street" >Address 1*</label>
       <input placeholder = "Address 1" class="form-control" formControlName="address1">
       <div *ngIf="(addressFormGroup.controls['address1'].errors)" class="error-msg">
        <div [hidden]="!addressFormGroup.controls['address1'].errors.required"
 class = "input_feedback">Address 1 is required.</div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

I have no issues with the values showing up, like "123 Elm Street" for the address1. However, the Validators no longer work like they used to when everything was just in the parent form. I've also tried setting validators using the setValidators() method, but that was not successful.

Comment: It turned out to not be an issue with my validators. The validators were passing fine. I had some Input decorators that were not set correctly and I had used them in the conditional statements with my validators, so it was my mistake to think it was an issue with the validators. Right now my issue is that the child form component's status is set to touched upon loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but I was able to recreate your form on StackBlitz and validation works as expected.

What I did was just pass `editUserForm_Address` `formGroup` to child component.

Here is working StackBlitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbfuut

```
<form [formGroup] = "editUserForm">
  <address-form [formGroup]="editUserForm.get('editUserForm_Address')"></address-form>
</form>
```

The key is passing the actual `formGroup` to child component -> `[formGroup]="editUserForm.get('editUserForm_Address')"`

Comment: It ended up being an issue with some Input decorators that I did not define properly in the child component class, but thank you very much for your example! I also had an issue setting the formgroup for the child component, and your answer helped.